# What does bit_reversed in #430 return for various input variables?

Tags: c, shader

I have a #430 shader here. I would like to reproduce this shader in `wgsl`. To do this, I have to understand what "bit_reversed" returns for a given number in order to be able to reproduce this as a function in `wgsl`.

Does anyone know about #430 and can say what `bit_reversed.j[int(x.y)]` e.g. `for x.y = 10, x.y = 50, x.y = 100, x.y = 200, ...` returns?

```c
#version 430 core
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 16) in;
layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) writeonly uniform image2D butterflyTexture;

layout (std430 , binding = 1) buffer indices {
    int j[ ];
} bit_reversed;

struct complex
{
    float real;
    float im;
};
uniform int N;

void main (void)
{
    vec2 x = gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy;
    float k = mod(x.y * (float(N) / pow( 2, x.x +1)), N);
    complex twiddle = complex(cos(2.0 *M_PI*k/ float(N)), sin(2.0 *M_PI*k/ float (N)));
    int butterflyspan = int(pow(2 , x.x));
    int butterflywing;
    if(mod(x.y , pow(2 , x.x + 1)) < pow( 2, x.x))

    butterflywing = 1;
    else butterflywing = 0;

    //firststage, bitreversed indices
    if(x.x == 0) {
        //top butterfly wing
        if(butterflywing == 1)
            imageStore(butterflyTexture, ivec2(x), vec4(twiddle.real, twiddle.im, 
            bit_reversed.j[int(x.y)], bit_reversed.j[int(x.y+1)]));
        //bot butterfly wing
        else
            imageStore(butterflyTexture , ivec2(x), vec4(twiddle.real, twiddle.im, 
            bit_reversed.j[int(x.y−1)], bit_reversed.j[int(x.y)]));
    }
    //second to log2(N) stage
    else{
        //top butterfly wing
        if(butterflywing == 1)
            imageStore(butterflyTexture, ivec2(x), vec4(twiddle.real, twiddle.im, 
            x.y, x.y + butterflyspan));
        //bot butterfly wing
        else
            imageStore(butterflyTexture, ivec2(x), vec4(twiddle.real, twiddle.im, 
            x.y − butterflyspan, x.y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely it reverses some bits (e.g., changing bits 1011 to 1101), but the code posted does not reveal how many bits its reverses.

Comment: That's exactly where my mistake was. I forgot to limit the number of bits so that 32 bits were always used. I just had to limit the number of bits depending on the image size with log2(imgSize). Then it worked.